# Terminal Colors: Substitute Dark Blue for Another Color

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, colors

Is it possible to "globally" substitute a terminal color somehow in OSX? In particular, I find that the dark blue is really hard on the eyes as demonstrated here:

[image: screenshot]

I'd love to be able to kick this color to the curb. It seems to be used throughout however: whether it's `vim`, or `ls`, or simply the prompt, I want it replaced with something lighter.

Answer (score 2):

Terminal has preferences like any other application. Try

Terminal --> Window Settings --> Color

They have some predefined themes and options for picking your own.

To edit from the command line, try this tutorial [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/) (cyberciti.biz)

Comment: The issue with this is when I ssh into my development VM, I inherit it's terminal colors for things such as listings. In a sense, I want to remap that dark blue color so regardless of where it's coming from, I get something like turquoise instead. Might be asking for the impossible ;)

Comment: I edited the answer to include a link to instructions for doing the same thing from the command line. The next time you ssh in, you can edit the .bashrc file following those instructions and problem solved.

Comment: @Yitzchak, Koobz is on Mac OS X. The default terminal doesn't let the user set his own colors apart from "bold", "background", "foreground" and "cursor".

Comment: @romainl However you can (at least on my father's old G5 running tiger) create a new profile and make it the default.

Comment: @Yitzchak, Yes you can create a profile — I did countless times — but you are still limited : there is no way in Terminal.app to actually change the value of `DarkMagenta` or `Cyan` or any other default color which is what Koobz wants. Whatever profile you use, `DarkGreen`will always be same color unless you use one of the two third party extensions available. On [this screenshot](http://imgur.com/HZ8nR) are 4 default profile and my custom profile all showing the same (customized) 16 colors.

Comment: Seemed to me he was looking for a way to change the colors to something slightly easier to read.  You can do that with the color choices OSX gives you.

Answer (score 2):

When using `ssh` the server only sends color codes, not values. The appearance of `Gray50` or `Red` are entirely dependant of your local settings therefore you have to tweak Terminal.app's color settings to your taste.

There are two SIMBL plugins that allow you to edit all of Terminal.app's 16 colors:

- [TerminalColoreopard](http://niw.at/articles/2007/11/02/TerminalColoreopard/en) by Yoshimasa Niwa
- [TerminalColors](http://ciaranwal.sh/2008/02/12/terminal-plug-in-updates) by Ciarán Walsh

With either one or the other your colorscheme of choice will be consistent when using `vim` locally or via `ssh`. Follow Ytzchak's link to have a similar prompt on the distant server and on your Mac. Maybe with different colors to know where you are.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer for newer MacOS versions:

Terminal => Preferences => Profiles (tab) => Text (sub-tab)

Under "ANSI Colors" set the 'blue' under 'normal' (and maybe also under 'bright'.

If you're changing the right one, you'll see the color change in your terminal in real time as you change the color in the color picker.